# Mule ESB with array input - how do I use use array-entry-point-resolver

Tags: arrays, mule

I have a webservice that exposes several methods taking arrays as an input.  I have defined a flow as required in the mule-config.xml file to my service implementation and can create my WCF client from the WSDL exposed by the service.

If I try to invoke one of these methods that accept an array as input from my client, I get the following exception:

```
WARN  2011-10-06 13:38:02,139 [connector.http.mule.default.receiver.3] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://api.data.ws.occ600.emsgt.com/}ConfigurationServiceService#{http://api.data.ws.occ600.emsgt.com/}create has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{configurationService.commponent.32217869}. Message payload is of type: MapExtent[]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:85)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleJAXWSInvoker.invoke(MuleJAXWSInvoker.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.sendToDestination(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:288)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.process(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.processor.SecurityFilterMessageProcessor.process(SecurityFilterMessageProcessor.java:77)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.processor.ExceptionHandlingMessageProcessor.process(ExceptionHandlingMessageProcessor.java:25)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:63)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:63)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:94)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:185)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:158)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:145)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.doRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:247)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:206)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:164)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:309)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.mule.component.ComponentException: Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{configurationService.commponent.32217869}. Message payload is of type: MapExtent[]
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:359)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:86)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:77)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:120)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:56)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:234)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:63)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:94)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:154)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:97)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:41)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:63)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:89)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:94)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1$1.process(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:107)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:328)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:80)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException: Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
ArrayEntryPointResolver: Found too many possible methods on object "com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2" that accept parameters "{class [Lcom.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.MapExtent;}", Methods matched are "[public final void com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2.delete(com.emsgt.data.api.EMSRecord[]) throws com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.DALException, public final com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.MapExtent[] com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2.create(com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.MapExtent[]) throws com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.DALException, public final void com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2.update(com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.MapExtent[]) throws com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.DALException, public final void com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2.createEx(com.emsgt.data.api.EMSRecord[]) throws com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.DALException, public final void com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2.updateOnly(com.emsgt.data.api.EMSRecord[]) throws com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.DALException, public final void com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2.updateOrInsert(com.emsgt.data.api.EMSRecord[]) throws com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.DALException]"
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "com.emsgt.occ600.ws.data.lib.ConfigurationServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7277bad2" with arguments: "{class com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.MapExtent,class com.emssatcom.occ600.dal.api.MapExtent}"
]
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:52)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:350)
```

Upon further investigation, I have found the array-entry-point-resolver. Adding this to my mule-config as follows

```
  <component>
           <entry-point-resolver-set>
                <reflection-entry-point-resolver/>
                <array-entry-point-resolver />
        </entry-point-resolver-set>

    <spring-object bean="myWebService"/>
</component>
```

still does not help.  Any experience with this anyone?

Comment: So I found the array-entry-point-resolver which helps but needs to be told which method to call, if two methods take same type and number of parameters.   Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of array-entry-point-resolvers, method-entry-point-resolvers and change in API signature to solve this problem.  The problem here is that Mule uses the argument of a webservice call to determine which method to use instead of the method name, even though its documentation states that is uses a bunch of resolvers, including the method-entry-point-resolver.

So, if you have an interface that exposes two differently named methods, both accepting a single array of type T, there is no combination of resolvers that will ensure the correct method is being called.  Not as far as I could tell.  If you specify both these methods in the  method-entry-point-resolver collection like this:

```
<method-entry-point-resolver>
                <include-entry-point method="method1"/>
                <include-entry-point method="method2"/> 
            </method-entry-point-resolver>
```

Mule always calls method1, if the input argument is T[], ignoring the method name.

If you try this:

```
<method-entry-point-resolver>
                <include-entry-point method="method1"/>                                         
            </method-entry-point-resolver>
            <array-entry-point-resolver>
               <include-entry-point method="method2"/>                 
            </array-entry-point-resolver>
```

Mule still does not call the correct method at all times.  So I ended up creating a class that simply wraps T[] and changed this as the input argument to method1.  Configured method1 in the collection of method-entry-point-resolvers and method2 in the collection of array-entry-point-resolvers and this works.

This is obviously a problem but I could not get the MuleSoft guys to respond.